# Downloading Random.py Using Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to download the random module and was wondering if I copy a code and put it in a file editor, how do I go about installing it through pip? I placed the code in notepad and saved it on my desktop as random.py. What do I do now so that I can get this in installed through anaconda? I tried pip install random.py but it says the package is not found. Is there perhaps a zip file of the random module that I can install?

Comment: The `random` module is part of the Python standard library. There is no need to install it separately.

Answer (score 2):

Just type in:

```
pip install random
```

It should work fine !
But the random module should be present by default with anaconda. Make sure you are importing it right by typing (without a capital letter):

```
import random
```

Answer (score 0):

If using python3, it will simply be
 `pip3 install random`

as @Remi stated.

Comment: I was just making sure this was covered since python-3.x was tagged in the original post.

Answer (score -1):

Use `pip install random`. That works with every Python distribution.

Comment: `random` is built-in, not installed with `pip`.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but this works with every module of python, not just with random.