# Can not download Random in python

Tags: python

I wanted to download random in python, I typed pip3 install random and it showed

```
c:/Users/pankajshukla>pip3 install random
Could Not Find A that satisfies the requirement random
No matching distribution found called random
```

I also tried pip install random and same thing (i am using python 3 for 32 bit)

EDIT EDIT EDIT:
So This was a old problem and a bad one
I knew it is pre installed but whenever i tried to `import random` It Throwed a module not found error.

This is now fixed for me

Comment: The random library comes with the stock python package, so there's no need to download anything. Have you tried `import random` yet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Downloading Random.py Using Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43709095/downloading-random-py-using-anaconda)

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to download it. Its part of the standard library and should already be installed

You can go ahead and use it in your program